Using permament running service in android
I am creating a privacy task calendar.
It uses an alarm manager and notifications. When the application is closed, the alarm service is apparently running and causing notifications. The notification has two actions - "set as completed" and "cancel". When I click "set as completed" in my task manager, there is nothing in the task list, because memory was freed, because the application is closed. A null pointer exception occurs.
Is it normal to use a constantly running service to store data, where you can set a task as completed?
Am I correct in understanding that WhatsApp uses a constantly running service with incoming message listener?
P.S. Sorry for my bad English. It's Google translate.
I cannot use the database, because it is encrypted. Only when I open the application, it is decrypted, and the task list is loaded into RAM.
I cannot use shared preferences, because there is a possibility of an information leak when connecting to a PC.
UPD:
TaskManager
    public Task getTaskById(int id) {
    Log.d("TaskCalendarLog", "Task manager getByID: task id = " + id);
    int index = 0;
    Log.d("TaskCalendarLog", "Task list = " + taskList);
    for (Task task:taskList) {//  <------- null pointer exception in taskList
        Log.d("TaskCalendarLog", "Task manager for: id = " + id);
        if (task.getId() == id) {
            return taskList.get(index);
        }
        index++;
    }
    return null;
}

TaskAlarmReciever
        Intent setDoneIntent = new Intent(context, ActionSetTaskDoneBroadcastReceiver.class);
    setDoneIntent.putExtra("id", taskId);
    PendingIntent setDonePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, setDoneIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

    NotificationCompat.Action cancel = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_cancel, "Cancel", cancelPendingIntent);
    NotificationCompat.Action setDone = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_done, "Set done", setDonePendingIntent);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "TaskNotificationChannel")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm)
            .setContentTitle("Task is now")
            .setContentText(taskText)
            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_ALARM)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setFullScreenIntent(taskAlarmPendingIntent, true)
            .setChannelId("TaskAlarmChannel")
            .addAction(cancel)
            .addAction(setDone)
            .setVibrate(new long[] {100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300, 400, 400, 500, 500, 400, 400, 300, 300, 200, 200, 100})
            .setAllowSystemGeneratedContextualActions(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(taskText))
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

ActionSetTaskDoneBroadcastReciever
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);
    TaskManager taskManager = TaskManager.getInstance();
    Log.d("TaskCalendarLog", "Action: task id = " + id);
    taskManager.getTaskById(id).setIsDone("true");
    TaskApplication.getInstance().restartAllTaskAlarm();

    Intent taskRintoneServiceIntent = new Intent(context, RingtoneService.class);
    context.stopService(taskRintoneServiceIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Log.d("TaskCalendarLog", "Notification id: " + id);
    notificationManager.cancel(id);
}


Constantly running services should generally be avoided. Can't you just send an intent to your app, which will start it and allow it to complete or cancel the task? Presumably the app itself can access its encrypted database.

"Is it normal to use a constantly running service to store data, where you can set a task as completed?" -- no. "Am I correct in understanding that WhatsApp uses a constantly running service with incoming message listener?" -- no.

@ewramner No, because I just need to mark the task as done: taskManager.getTaskById(id).setIsDone("true");
In TaskManager there is a List that stores tasks. When I receive a task, I need to mark it as Done, however, when I close the application, the List becomes Null. This is my problem, because when the AlarmManager is triggered, I cannot mark the task as done.

Make sure to include a key in the notification that allows you to trigger your app with an intent so that the app knows you are trying to mark a given task as done. Then the app can do it and load the task from the data store as it is gone from memory. It doesn't really have to display anything.

@ewramner How can i make it?

Start by posting code in your question. It is easier for us to help adjust the code if we can see it.

@ewramner Done.

Still need help.
